# How to make a number alignment in JSON?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am working on a command list command in JSON and I am having troubles with making a number alignment in the code.

```
@client.command()
async def command_list(ctx):
  with open("commands.json", "r") as f:
    y = json.load(f)

    embed = discord.Embed(description="\n".join(y[str(ctx.guild.id)]),
    colour=discord.Colour())
    embed.set_author(name=ctx.author, icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

I want it to be sent like this:

```
 1. <1stcommandname>
 2. <2ndcommandname>
 3. <3rdcommandname>
 ...
```

Comment: What happens instead?

Comment: It just sends it as a list:

Commandname1
Commandname2
commandname3

Comment: Apparently you need to format some numbers into the string passed to `discord.Embed`, according to your requirements.

Comment: You got it right.